# How many custom claims can one user account have in Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've recently tried setting custom claims and noticed that an account I previously added custom claims to lost those claims. I know for a fact they set correctly, so after some testing I noticed that they appeared to be overwritten by new custom claims.

I'd like to know if this is intentional, does that mean only one custom claim can be set on a user account at a time? If so, how might one set multiple access permissions to a single Firebase Auth account? (Ex: `marketing` and `IT` OR `admin` and `support`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

There is only one "blob" of custom claims per account.  This blob has a limit of 1000 bytes, as stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk):

> Custom claims payload must not exceed 1000 bytes.

The provided SDKs that work with custom claims interpret this blob of data as a JSON object, so you can put whatever you want in there that can be expressed as JSON.

When you set new custom claims, it overwrites the old claims.  This is also stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk):

> Note: this operation always overwrites the user's existing custom claims. However, if the same custom user claims are defined on a user signed in via custom authentication, the overlapping claims defined in the custom token have higher priority and always overwrite the custom user claims defined on a user via this API.

So, if you want to modify the claims, you will need to read them, modify that blob, then write the modified blob back to Firebase

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. So it looks like multiple claims have to nest within that blob. Thanks.